# Type inference in dart curried function

Tags: dart, type-inference

I know Typescript's type system allows some pretty intricate inferences, and I'm wondering how far I can push dart.

I want to create a simple utility function that delays a Future by currying.

```dart
Future<T> Function(Future<T> fut) delay<T>(Duration dur) =>
    (fut) async => (await Future.wait(
          [Future.delayed(dur), fut],
        ))[1] as T;
```

The problem with this is that I have to pass T to the delay function, like this:

```dart
final delayedPosition<Position>(Duration(seconds: 3));


// later
await delayedPosition(someFutureThatReturnsAPosition);
```

Ideally, I'd like Dart to infer the type the future is returning so I wouldn't have to specify it myself.

Is this possible? If so, how would it look?

EDIT:

To be clear, what I want to do is to **not** have to make `delay` generic and the return type of function returned from `delay` be inferred from it's argument. This seems to be causing confusion.

e.g.

```dart
// declare delay - I don't know what it should look like

final thingThatDelaysAFutureBy3Seconds = delay(Duration(seconds: 3));

// later
final valFromFuture = await thingThatDelaysAFutureBy3Seconds(someFuture);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is here, it is not possible infer the type from the function you provided since there is not context where T is used that can be used to infer the type.

Also the example code you sent is not valid and you are not waiting 5 seconds before running the future as well, but is waiting 5 seconds before returning the future value (but it is ran concurrently with the delay) if you want to run the future *after* the delay has been passed you should instead use:

```dart
Future<T> Function(Future<T> fut) delay<T>(Duration dur) => (fut) async {
      await Future.delayed(dur);
      return fut;
    };
```

Example:

```dart
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var f = delay<int>(Duration(seconds: 5));
  var v = await f(f1()); // Inferred as int
  print(v);
}

Future<int> f1() => Future.value(1);
```

Comment: The intention is correct, I want to wait at least duration before returning the value

Comment: What I would like to be able to do is to just pass a future, any type, to the curried function and have the return type inferred from the argument passed to it.

Comment: If you the function the variable type is inferred correctly, see the updated code